# How to run game on one monitor and have programs on other monitor still visible?

Tags: multiple-monitors, games

How can i make programs on second monitor still visible while playing game (Wolfenstein: Enemy Territory)?

I know that i can use windowed mode, but playing in windowed kinda feels different, like game has a lot of tiny video lags.

EDIT1: I am running gnome on latest ubuntu, and while one monitor has game on it and other is completely black (my notifications are set up so they pop up on second monitor) i can see notifications (libnotify and skype).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windowed is as good as I've got, I'm afraid but to be fair, doing it any other way will be just as laggy because the system is rendering more. It's overlaying your game on a desktop as well as the other uncovered desktop and those applications, so yeah, it's a little more intensive and that's going to hurt in-game performance.

Coincidentally, I also use Compiz to make certain screen-sized windows render with fullscreen hinting (so they show above the panel, without window decoration). You can do this by opening CCSM (`compizconfig-settings-manager`), heading down to Window Rules, enabling it and entering a rule for your game's window.

This won't help performance, it'll just make it look how you'd expect.

Comment: Ok, i tried playing it in windowed mode, and game is fluid as usual, i have created other question descibing problem where game locks focus and i cant change to some other window.
http://askubuntu.com/q/22303/6564

Answer (score 0):

Somehow was possible to make start programm in one of screens.
But how to get mouse go out of game?
Another way to try would be using 2 computers and one set of PC controlers (mouse/keyb) using programm Quick-Synergy. With it u can move mouse to end of screen and control other PC.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to juice the last bit of performance out of your Ubuntu gaming setup install fluxbox and run your games from that. It may lack the cute bells and whistles that you're used to, but it will have better performance. That said: windowed is as good as it gets. (See above)

Also in fluxbox the CCSM trick is unavailable so you'd have to do it manually.