# How to use loose focus feature of Xserver?

Tags: window-manager, xorg, focus

I want one window to loose mouse focus (its a game, and alt-tab doesnt work as it should).

There is this interesting commit that i reached with searching and reading, but dont know how to use DeaGrb feature.

http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~daniels/xserver/commit/?h=input-next&id=ff4efa75fba16c099295b0cc6a5b9e44386b8427

Edit1:
There are some applications(games mostly) which exclusively grab mouse focus, and if you press alt-tab, your mouse focus wont switch to another window, I want to force such applications to release all focus they have, i think that `AllowDeactivateGrabs` config var in X server should have similar effect, but it is deprecated...

Edit2: @poolie, no it is not duplicate question, it is releated, but definetely not duplicate

Comment: Just what do you mean by "loose mouse focus"?  Do you mean you don't want alt-tab to work in that window?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [question 22303](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22303/)?  If so, please don't spam multiple questions about the same problem.  Just make the original question clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an X expert, but I don't think that patch is really relevant to having different focus behaviour between different windows.

If you are asking for just some windows to use focus-follows-mouse, you can probably configure that into a sufficiently flexible window manager.  It might be possible in Compiz; it's almost certainly possible in Sawfish.

If your problem is just that the game uses Alt-tab for its own purposes, you can just remove that from the Ubuntu *Keyboard Shortcuts* configuration window.